# How can I create a service account user in Jenkins alongside other users from a Security Realm like SSO or LDAP?

Tags: jenkins

In my organisation, service account users cannot be added to our SSO identity provider. Is there a way I can add a user to Jenkins' system and then create a token for it?

There is no requirement for this user to actually be able to login.

The ability to make accounts alongside the security realm accounts appears to be a limitation in Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-38257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on our setup which uses a SAML security realm with Okta SSO - an admin can run the following from the script console:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import jenkins.security.*
import jenkins.security.apitoken.*

def userName = 'service-account-name'
def tokenName = 'service-access-token'

def user = User.get(userName, true) // `true` will create the user if it does not exist.
def token = user.getProperty(ApiTokenProperty.class).tokenStore.generateNewToken(tokenName)
user.save()

return token.plainValue
```

The result will output the token that can be used in API requests. If the user already exists then it will add a new token to the user.

Any created or pre-existing token can be revoked from the user's page under People.